# JIT compilation of Optional

Tags: java, option-type, jit

Not so much a question but an observation.

I'm somewhat surprised that the JIT compiler doesn't inline the use of the Optional class since it seems to be a heavily used part of the language since Java 8.  I was expecting the following two test methods to perform equivalent:

```java
    import static java.util.Optional.*;

    public static class TestClass {

        int i;

        public void test1(Integer x) {
            i = ofNullable(x).orElse(-1);
        }

        public void test2(Integer x) {
            if (x == null)
                i = -1;
            else
                i = x;
        }
    }
```

Instead, test1 always allocates an Optional for non-null values and is therefore 20x slower than test2.  It just seems like this code should be easily optimized by the JIT compiler.

I tested this on Java 8 and Java 11.  Anyone know if newer versions of Java do a better job at optimizing this?  In general I like the terseness of using ofNullable over if/else statements, but I can't use them in critical code paths due to heavy GC.

Edit:  Here's the benchmarking code I used:

```java
@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 100, warmupRounds = 20)
public class BenchmarkTest {
    @Rule
    public TestRule benchmarkRun = new BenchmarkRule();

    public static Integer[] ARRAY;

    /** Prepare random numbers for tests. */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        ARRAY = new Integer[10000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            ARRAY[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? null : i;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        TestClass x = new TestClass();
        for (int a = 0; a < ARRAY.length; a++) {
            x.test1(ARRAY[a]);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        TestClass x = new TestClass();
        for (int a = 0; a < ARRAY.length; a++) {
            x.test2(ARRAY[a]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you benchmark this? It takes quite a bit of execution time before the jit kicks in.

Comment: Added the benchmarking code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the more readable way like the `Optional` provides, but also want to control JIT. You coould write a simple class that JIT can easily inline.

```
package util;


public class OptionalInteger {

    public interface NullableInt {
        public int orElse(int defaultValue);
    }

    public static NullableInt ofNullable(Integer integer) {
        return new NullableInt() {

            @Override
            public int orElse(int elseValue) {
                return integer == null ? elseValue : integer;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Your client code will almost look the same.

```
import static util.OptionalInteger.ofNullable;

public class TestClass {

    int i;

    public void test1(Integer x) {
        i = ofNullable(x).orElse(-1);
    }

}
```

But JIT easily recognizes that it can be inlined.

[image: JIT elliminated allocations]

---

Here is the test code

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            Integer inte = random.nextBoolean() ? random.nextInt() : null;
            integers.add(inte);
        }

        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        warmUpJIT(integers, testClass);

        execWithMeasurement(testClass, integers);
    }

    private static void warmUpJIT(List<Integer> integers, TestClass testClass) {
        exec(testClass, integers);
        exec(testClass, integers);
        exec(testClass, integers);
        exec(testClass, integers);
    }

    private static void execWithMeasurement(TestClass testClass, List<Integer> integers) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int result = exec(testClass, integers);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String msg = MessageFormat.format("Result {0} - took {1} ms", result, (end - start));
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    private static int exec(TestClass testClass, List<Integer> integers) {
        int result = 0;

        for (Integer integer : integers) {
            testClass.test1(integer);
            result += testClass.i;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I used [JITclipse](https://jitclipse.io/), an eclipse integration for JITWatch that I wrote some time ago.

Comment: Interesting idea!

Comment: I just tested and that performs just as well as an if/else block.  Thanks!

Comment: “ control JIT” is a misleading phrase. Your class doesn’t control the JIT in any way. If you want to find out, why this class gets optimized better than `Optional`, you’d have to analyze the differences between these two classes. My guess is that this is an optimization attempt that backfires: `Optional.of(null)` returns a shared single object instead of allocating a new one; your `OptionalInteger` always returns a new object, which is a uniform behavior, easier to optimize. And indeed, when you change the test data to contain no `null`, `Optional` gets optimized the same way.

Comment: @JamesBognar if you really think, you have to replace a simple `x != null? x: -1` with something that hides what’s going on, you can use [`Objects.requireNonNullElse(x, -1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)).

Comment: @Holger what I mean is that I provide a structure that JIT usually recognizes as optimizable. E.g. I return an anonymous class of the `NullableInt` interface. Since the type can never change a virtual invocation is not necesarry. Thus JIT usually inlines the called code. I hope that I was clear in what I mean.

Comment: @Holger I also find your more simple solution `Objects.requireNonNullElse(x, -1)` also very good. I just tried to make an example that looks like the `Optional` api. Just add another answer.

Comment: @Holger - I guess it's more of an aesthetic reason.  A ternary is fine, but in general I find using ofNullable() easier to read:   

`Day day1 = string != null ? Day.valueOf(string) : Day.MONDAY;`  

`Day day2 = ofNullable(string).map(Day::valueOf).orElse(Day.MONDAY);`  

If you're performing lots of null checks, the ternaries quickly start looking like a mess.